# S#arp Lite - NHibernate Initializer not finding named connection string

Tags: nhibernate, s#arp

I am attempting to use S#arp Lite. I have followed the instructions here - https://github.com/codai/Sharp-Lite/blob/master/README.txt

When I first attempt to run the `MappingIntegrationTests` in NUnit, I receive the following errors:

```
MySolution.Tests.NHibernateProvider.MappingIntegrationTests.CanConfirmDatabaseMatchesMappings:
SetUp : NHibernate.HibernateException : Could not find named connection string MySolutionConnectionString
MySolution.Tests.NHibernateProvider.MappingIntegrationTests.CanConfirmDatabaseMatchesMappings:
SetUp : NHibernate.HibernateException : Could not find named connection string MySolutionConnectionString
```

NUnit indicates that the above errors are coming from the second line of the `SetUp` method in `MappingIntegrationTests`.

```
[SetUp]
public virtual void SetUp() {
  _configuration = NHibernateInitializer.Initialize();
  _sessionFactory = _configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
}
```

The `Initialize` method of my `NHibernateInitializer` class,

```
public static Configuration Initialize() {
  Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
  configuration.Proxy(p => p.ProxyFactoryFactory<DefaultProxyFactoryFactory>())
               .DataBaseIntegration(db => {
                   db.ConnectionStringName = "MySolutionConnectionString";
                   db.Dialect<MsSql2008Dialect>();
               })
               .AddAssembly(typeof(ActionConfirmation<>).Assembly)
               .CurrentSessionContext<LazySessionContext>();
  ConventionModelMapper mapper = new ConventionModelMapper();
  mapper.WithConventions(configuration);
  return configuration;
}
```

And the `App.Config` file from `MySolution.Tests` project,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MySolutionConnectionString" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MySolutionDB-DEV;Integrated Security=SSPI" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </ connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

I don't understand why the NUnit test runner is failing with the message `Could not find named connection string MySolutionConnectionString`. According to James Kovacs' blog post on Loquacious Configuration, this seems like this should work no problem -

> "Setting db.ConnectionStringName causes NHibernate to read the connection string from the  config section of the [App|Web].config."

Answer (score 0):

`MySolution.Tests` is a dll but App.configs are only read for the starting .exe file which is the NUnit testrunner.